# Legend in slice of Pie chart in silverlight

Tags: pie-chart, legend

I have pie chart developped in VS using silverlight.
I have a legend with the colors of each slice.
However, I want to show above each pie slice, the legend and it's value. It's possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart
            x:Name="PieChart"
            Margin="50,0,44,0"
            Grid.Row="7"
            Title="{Binding SelectedGraphOptions, Mode=OneWay}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="478" 
            Visibility="{Binding PieChartVisibility}">
            <chartingToolkit:PieSeries
                ItemsSource="{Binding Data}"
                IndependentValueBinding="{Binding XAxis}"
                DependentValueBinding="{Binding YAxis}" />              
        </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```